# In VS code i want this sticky line to no appear when i scroll. is there any setting for this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Sticky VS Code Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEDtj.png)

Open the above image to see what I am talking about.

In VS code I want this sticky line to not appear when I scroll. Is there any setting for this?
Tried to browse in the setting but couldn't find please help.

In VS code I want this sticky line to not appear when I scroll. Is there any setting for this?
Tried to browse in the setting but couldn't find please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's called Sticky Scroll. You may search with wrong name.

[image: Sticky Scroll]